# Make a covariance matrix have a larger eigenvalue for one eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

Suppose I have a covariance matrix $\Sigma$, with eigenvalues $u_1,u_2,u_3$ and eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$. How can I use that information to generate a new covariance matrix $\Sigma_2$ with the same eigenvectors but with some new eigenvalues $\alpha u_1, u_2, u_3$?

Comment: $\Sigma+(\alpha-1)u_{1}\times v_{1}v_{1}^{T}$ (assuming your eigenvalues are orthonormalized).

Comment: @RideTheWavelet I ended up figuring it out, but thanks.